# android using shared preferences issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
static int existingCounter;

    Context mContext = SplashScreen.getContextOfApplication();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    public static int cCounter() 
    {       
        MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
        existingCounter = mm.getExistingCounter();;

    return existingCounter;
    }

    public void setSharedPreferences(int count) 
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myCounter", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("existingCount", existingCounter);

        editor.commit();
    }

    //Get value from shared preferences
    public int getExistingCounter() 
    {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myCounter", 0);
        myPrefs.getInt("existingCount", 0);

        return existingCounter ;
    }
```

Hi all, above is my shared preferences. What I am trying to achieve is when user 1st launch the app, my app shall direct user to the disclaimer page and after the user agree to the T&C then in future the user launch the app shall not show the disclaimer page again. However, my current codes only valid when user never exit app. If the user were to exit the app and relaunch, my app still shows the disclaimer page. Please assist =) Thank you in advance. Below is the part where I set the sharedpreferences:

```
case 3:
            cCounter();
            if(existingCounter==0)
            {
                changeMenuFrag(new AcknowledgePg());
                existingCounter++;
                setSharedPreferences(existingCounter);
            }
            else
            {
                changeMenuFrag(new GalleryMain());
            }           
            break;
```

Comment: why not use the PreferenceManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a flag in the Preferences when you start up the application, after you've done the welcome screen stuff. Check for this flag before you show the T&C screen. If the flag is present (in other words, if it's not the first time), don't show it. Instead of a integer counter use a boolean flag and in your main activity check if the flag is true or false based on that show the appropriate activity.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
final String welcomeScreenShownPref = "welcomeScreenShown";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

if (!welcomeScreenShown) {
    // here you can launch another activity if you like


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
    editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference}
```

}